# What causes a deleted Content Item to remain published?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I have encountered a case where I have a Content Item that is both deleted and published. This has only happened twice out of roughly 10,000 content items. So, I believe it to be rare.

By deleted and published, I mean there are no Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord records with a Latest = true, for a given Content Item. Yet, for that same Content Item, there is at least one version record that has a Published = true value.

This results in an end-user being able to search for, find and access the content item. The end-user can do this, even though the content item was deleted (from the Orchard admin dashboard).

I have tried to come up with a story that explains how this could happen. I've installed the Version Manager module (so I could easily un-delete content items and monitor the state of the version records in the database). Then I tried the following:

1. Deleting a published item. This results in a collection of version records (for the content item) for which none are Latest, or Published.
2. Deleting an unpublished item. This results in the same (a collection of version records where Latest = 0 and  Published = 0).
3. I've confirmed that there are no Workflows set up that have anything to do with content item state.

Is there anyone out there who has encountered this, or (even better) figured out how it happened and knows how to keep it from happening again?

(I am running Orchard version 1.9.2.0)

Comment: Is there any chance double clicking the publish button? Then, it would create a duplicate version item...

Comment: I face similar problems before, with multi users sites, where it is possible that more than one user may edit the same content item at the same time and do publish together, this case will produce some corrupted data

Comment: @mdameer I think you are most likely right. This is the case with my setup. There are multiple admin users all working at the same time. The corrupted data was easy to clean up. And it hasn't happened again.

Comment: I've encountered this behavior yesterday and can reproduce it consistently. Haven't had the time to debug it properly yet, but it definitely looks like a bug (1.10.x)